# Can not add bullets for word using OpenXml

Tags: openxml, docx, openxml-sdk

My expected result is:

- Hello
- world!

but when i using below codes:

```
        MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart =
          package.AddMainDocumentPart();

        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document elementW =
          new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document(
            new Body(
              new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(
                    new NumberingProperties(
                      new NumberingLevelReference() { Val = 0 },
                      new NumberingId() { Val = 1 })
                    ),
                new Run(
                  new RunProperties(),
                  new Text("Hello, ") { Space = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpaceProcessingModeValues> { InnerText = "preserve" } })),
              new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(
                new ParagraphProperties(
                  new NumberingProperties(
                    new NumberingLevelReference() { Val = 0 },
                    new NumberingId() { Val = 1 })),
                new Run(
                  new RunProperties(),
                  new Text("world!")
                  {
                      Space = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpaceProcessingModeValues> { InnerText = "preserve" }
                  })));

        elementW.Save(mainDocumentPart);
```

Result is:

1. Hello
2. world!

How can i get my expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should create you a blank document with your expected output:

```
        // Creates an Document instance and adds its children.
        public Document GenerateDocument()
        {
            Document document1 = new Document();
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("ve", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("m", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("v", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wp", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w10", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
            document1.AddNamespaceDeclaration("wne", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml");

            Body body1 = new Body();

            Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphAddition = "00AF4948", RsidParagraphProperties = "00625634", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00625634" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId1 = new ParagraphStyleId(){ Val = "ListParagraph" };

            NumberingProperties numberingProperties1 = new NumberingProperties();
            NumberingLevelReference numberingLevelReference1 = new NumberingLevelReference(){ Val = 0 };
            NumberingId numberingId1 = new NumberingId(){ Val = 1 };

            numberingProperties1.Append(numberingLevelReference1);
            numberingProperties1.Append(numberingId1);

            paragraphProperties1.Append(paragraphStyleId1);
            paragraphProperties1.Append(numberingProperties1);

            Run run1 = new Run();
            Text text1 = new Text();
            text1.Text = "Hello";

            run1.Append(text1);

            paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
            paragraph1.Append(run1);

            Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph(){ RsidParagraphAddition = "00625634", RsidParagraphProperties = "00625634", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00625634" };

            ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties2 = new ParagraphProperties();
            ParagraphStyleId paragraphStyleId2 = new ParagraphStyleId(){ Val = "ListParagraph" };

            NumberingProperties numberingProperties2 = new NumberingProperties();
            NumberingLevelReference numberingLevelReference2 = new NumberingLevelReference(){ Val = 0 };
            NumberingId numberingId2 = new NumberingId(){ Val = 1 };

            numberingProperties2.Append(numberingLevelReference2);
            numberingProperties2.Append(numberingId2);

            paragraphProperties2.Append(paragraphStyleId2);
            paragraphProperties2.Append(numberingProperties2);

            Run run2 = new Run();
            Text text2 = new Text();
            text2.Text = "world!";

            run2.Append(text2);

            paragraph2.Append(paragraphProperties2);
            paragraph2.Append(run2);

            SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties(){ RsidR = "00625634", RsidSect = "00AF4948" };
            HeaderReference headerReference1 = new HeaderReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Even, Id = "rId7" };
            HeaderReference headerReference2 = new HeaderReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = "rId8" };
            FooterReference footerReference1 = new FooterReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Even, Id = "rId9" };
            FooterReference footerReference2 = new FooterReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.Default, Id = "rId10" };
            HeaderReference headerReference3 = new HeaderReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.First, Id = "rId11" };
            FooterReference footerReference3 = new FooterReference(){ Type = HeaderFooterValues.First, Id = "rId12" };
            PageSize pageSize1 = new PageSize(){ Width = (UInt32Value)12240U, Height = (UInt32Value)15840U };
            PageMargin pageMargin1 = new PageMargin(){ Top = 1440, Right = (UInt32Value)1440U, Bottom = 1440, Left = (UInt32Value)1440U, Header = (UInt32Value)720U, Footer = (UInt32Value)720U, Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U };
            Columns columns1 = new Columns(){ Space = "720" };
            DocGrid docGrid1 = new DocGrid(){ LinePitch = 360 };

            sectionProperties1.Append(headerReference1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(headerReference2);
            sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference2);
            sectionProperties1.Append(headerReference3);
            sectionProperties1.Append(footerReference3);
            sectionProperties1.Append(pageSize1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(pageMargin1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(columns1);
            sectionProperties1.Append(docGrid1);

            body1.Append(paragraph1);
            body1.Append(paragraph2);
            body1.Append(sectionProperties1);

            document1.Append(body1);
            return document1;
        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between bullet and number? It seems both are using NumberingProperties. But on my computer, i didn't get my expected result yet. Is there any differences about version or somthing else?

Answer (score 9):

I realize this is far too late but maybe it can help others with the same question.  The marked answer (by amurra) doesn't actually achieve the desired result.  It simply creates a document with the list as content, just more completely than you.  What you have added to the main document part is fine.

In the XML format, list items are defined as paragraphs with an indentation level and a numbering ID.  This ID references the numbering rules defined in the NumberingDefinitionsPart of the document.

In your case, because you've set the numbering ID to be 1, the following code would map that ID of 1 to reflect a bulleted list as desired.  Note the NumberingFormat and LevelText objects inside the Level object.  These are the key components for your formatting.

```cs
NumberingDefinitionsPart numberingPart =
    mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<NumberingDefinitionsPart>("myCustomNumbering");

Numbering numElement = new Numbering(
    new AbstractNum(
        new Level(
            new NumberingFormat() { Val = NumberFormatValues.Bullet },
            new LevelText() { Val = "·" }
        ) { LevelIndex = 0 }
    ) { AbstractNumberId = 0 },
    new NumberingInstance(
        new AbstractNumId(){ Val = 0 }
    ){ NumberID = 1 }
);

numElement.Save(numberingPart);
```

For more information, check out the documentation for all the related classes on the [Wordprocessing Namespace on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.aspx), or the [Working With Numbering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee922775%28v=office.14%29.aspx#odc_Office14_ta_WorkingWithNumbering_MarkupSimple) markup article.

Comment: +1 Improving on answers even after-the-fact helps others down the road. This is what SO is about.